# Google Libraries - URL version selecting

Tags: javascript, api

Reading through documentation,

I found following:

```
1.9.1
1.8.4
1.8.2
```

> A version of "1.8.2" select the
>   obvious, fully-specified version.
>   Specifying a version of "1.8" would
>   select 1.8.4 since this is the highest
>   version released in the 1.8 branch.
>   For much the same reason, a request
>   for "1" loads version 1.9.1, since
>   this is the highest version released
>   in the 1 branch. Note, these
>   versioning semantics work the same way
>   when using google.load and when using
>   **direct script urls**.

Does that mean, that I can use something like

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
```

and I get latest jQuery v1.** ?

Or, would it be even possible to include:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just testing the two URL you gave :

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js
```

This doesn't work : I get a 404 error.

So, it seems you must specify at least the major version number *(i.e. the first digit in 1.4.2)* -- which seems reasonable, as a change in major version number generally means a big change in the API *(which will probably require you to change stuff in your application)*.

And with the first one :

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
```

I get jQuery 1.4.2 -- which is indeed the most recent version.

And if I test with [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) :

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1/prototype.js
```

I get the most recent version too.

Comment: I should be less lazy and test it myself.. however, 25 rep for you :)

Comment: Thanks ^^ -- Actually, your question interested me *(I had never quite asked myself that question)*, so testing it was useful for me too :-)